# How to find newly registered projects in github

Tags: github

How to find newly registered projects in github. Is there a way to get a notification when a new project is registered / submitted to the github public repository.

Comment: Are you looking for *any* new projects? Or just new projects for a specific account?

Comment: I would like to know projects originating from a certain github account as well as projects under a certain tag or projects created in github itself.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know there is any API or notification mechanism in github for this. But you can check this page for "just now" timeline :)

https://github.com/timeline

Basically, whenever a new project is created in github, this timeline page will display "<user name> created repository <repo name> jut now"

I am also eager to know if there is any direct approach to get the info. Any experts?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of such a service, but you could search github for recently created projects [like this](https://github.com/search?q=created%3a%5BNOW-1DAY%20TO%20NOW%5D&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Repositories):

```
created:[NOW-1DAY TO NOW]
```